# Script Execution when Switching Sheets withing the Same Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm running an online booking sheet for my local squash club (dragging them into this century!) and need to find an easy way to automate navigation to the current date when #1 opening the spreadsheet, an #2 switching sheets while the spreadsheet is open. Without the feature, people will have to endlessly scroll through the season to find today's date.

I've run a formula in column A that will place an * on the row that =TODAY() and would appreciate a bit of advice from people with script writing skills as to whether it would be possible to go to that cell on start up, and when we switch between sheets (we run 2 courts, on separate sheets).

As always, help is very much appreciated, and hopefully there is something that can be introduced that can help.

**[edit] I suppose the simplest way, looking back at it now, would be the following I just need to learn how to code it:**

OnOpen - Set the active sheet as "COURT 1"

Set the active range for the function as A:A

Go to the last modified cell in that range (as it's always going to the be the cell that I want).

The script should then repeat the process for "COURT 2" and then return to  "COURT 1".

Copy of the spreadsheet can be found here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NBom_qB9AM_LG2lgrGjNRDbxbSGysVj8H6AXqdgKWD8/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks :)

Mark

Comment: How's the spreadsheet organized? Perhaps you can share a copy.  What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for the response OP Updated with a link to a copy of the spreadsheet. What I'm trying to do is navigate to the * in column A when I switch sheets (within the spreadsheet). I'm not sure if it's possible to set a script to run when you switch sheets, rather than on open.

Answer (score 0):

Some key concepts that might help. I highly advise that you learn how to script so you don't go asking for code each time you want to modify something.

To run a script upon opening the sheet, you can make use of [onOpen() trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onopen). On the same note, you need to be aware of this [trigger's Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions).

To operate on another sheet within the same SpreadSheet, use [setActiveSheet(sheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#setActiveSheet(Sheet)). When the sheet becomes active, you can now do operations on it. Check the [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) for more docs info.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have been doing some code academy basic courses to gain a bit more understanding.
I've updated the OP to show a link to a copy of my sheet, and while I understand the onOpen function (to an extent, I use it in my current script) what I needed to know is if there is a way of automating a script function when a user changes between sheets (in the open spreadsheet). That script would find the * in column A and navigate to it.
If I use a last modified cell script, though it finds the last modified cell on opening, it loses its place when switching between sheets.